# Azure functions don't compile

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a service app created and I created some functions inside that.

Now, when I made some change on my code and click on save button, the function isn't compile even with syntax errors.

If I create a new service app everthing works fine but I already have an API management over this service app and import all the functions could be a problem.

Comment: Can you share your function app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Also, does restarting the app fix the issue?

Comment: Is this still relevant / happening or can this question be closed?